# Is it safe to override queryset in a custom django-rest-framework action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a queryset like this

```py
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    queryset = Data.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='viewers/sum')
    def viewers_sum(self, request):
        self.queryset = Data.objects.filter(foo="bar").order_by('-foo')
        return super().list(request)
```

As you can see I override queryset in the custom action `viewers_sum`. My question is if this has risk to cause issue with other actions, like `list()`. I've had similar problems before with permission where I've overwritten some property that's hasn't been restored for the next request.

I've tried to debug this and It seems like there's no problem, but I don't understand the reason behind it. And it might not behave the same on production server as in my dev-server.

In the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) they're not using this method. But I would prefer this since it feels very clean (if it's safe).

**EDIT**

I guess the question boils down to:
Does Django create a new instance of ViewSets with every request, or is it one persistent instance?

**EDIT 2**

I read through the source-code and found that you can pass kwargs to override.
Not sure if this is "safe" either though. Seems like it's working, but again, that's in debug server.

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    queryset = Data.objects.all()

    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=['get'],
        url_path='viewers',
        queryset=Data.objects.none()
    )
    def viewers_sum(self, request):
        return super().list(request)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queryset` is a class variable and you are altering the value of `queryset` inside the `viewers_sum(...)` method.

As a result, the value of `queryset` is not getting changed once the `viewers_sum(...)` called, and there is the side-effect.

---

#### What is the best practice?

You can override the **`get_queryset(...)`** method as,

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.action == "viewers_sum":
            return Data.objects.filter(foo="bar").order_by('-foo')
        return Data.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='viewers/sum')
    def viewers_sum(self, request):
        return super().list(request)
```

Comment: I added an edit to my original post, do you know if that's a safe method to use?

Comment: I think we can pass the class variables that end with ***`_class`*** (for ex. `serializer_class`), So, I don't think `queryset` comes under this criteria. btw, could you pass me the source code that you refereed?

Comment: I think you are right. This page under `def action()`. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/decorators.py#L123